# how to accept any path in Spring boot + MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to define an endpoint using Spring Boot + MVC that accepts a multipart file upload containing a desired target path in the url.

Example:

form the url `http://localhost:8080/upload/file/path/to/somefile.pdf` I expect to extract `/path/to/somefile.pdf` to use it later.

So far this is what I got:

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.PUT, value="/file/**", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
@ResponseBody
public UploadResult uploadFile(final HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
  //parse from path is ok.
}
```

It captures any path (slashes included) *but* files suffixes. So this works:

```
http://localhost:8080/upload/file/path/to/somefile
```

but this doesn't

```
http://localhost:8080/upload/file/path/to/somefile.pdf
```

It answers a `406` caused by `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`.

I assume the framework is trying to infer something regarding the pdf, and don't know to handle it. I assume it's only a configuration issue... How can I stop that behavior for only that endpoint?

*Failed Attempts:*

- tried turning off the suffix pattern match from WebMvcConfigurerAdapter as someone suggested

  `configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);`

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by  "accept any path in Spring boot + MVC" and what actually you are trying to acheive in above example

Comment: @Sam ok, I've rewritten the question and added a more verbose example at the top. You are right, people might not read after the first sentence. I think it's more clear now, thank for the heads up.

Comment: @estani I would try to remove the suffix of your request, according to your method name, what you need is the path to upload, then the file name and suffix is something you could easily extract from the MultipartFIle. Is a requeriment accept the file name in the URL?

Comment: I think here something went wrong while detecting the media type of the requested URL as mentioned in below link http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer.html#favorPathExtension-boolean-

Comment: @cralfaro that's the workaround for now (i.e. using content disposition and url as path), but it doesn't look right `PUT ../id` and `GET ../id/filename.ext` should be the same.

Comment: @Sam awesome. That was exactly the parameter that handled it. I don't think it's possible to define it per endpoint, but in my case might work out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException or 406 means we have problems with Content Negotiation. By default spring will first check with the path extension. 
In your case, your endpoint have suffix with .pdf, so it is expecting as application.pdf or pdf is required but your end point defined something else. So it gives 406 error. you can check more details here
<https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc>

To resolve the issue you can easily change this configuration using ContentNegotiationConfigurer accessed by extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. 



 @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

      @Override
      public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
      }
    }
```

Comment: In works for me, and I don't think it's possible to set it per endpoint anyways. Thanks.